# A more effective way to do perspective transformation

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Following some tutorial I have an image taken from a camera (already undistorted) and would like to do a perspective transform so as to have the image from a different perspective.

In the tutorial we do this like:

[image: Perspective transformation]

```
src=np.float32([[850,320],[865,450],[533,350],[535,210]])
dst=np.float32([[870,240],[870,370],[520,370],[520,240]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, img_size, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

which is fine, but there is something that worries me, and actually later found in the tutorial

> Note: When you apply a perspective transform, choosing four source
> points manually, as we did in this video, is often not the best
> option. There are many other ways to select source points. For
> example, many perspective transform algorithms will programmatically
> detect four source points in an image based on edge or corner
> detection and analyzing attributes like color and surrounding pixels.

My question is, what would be a good way to do this not-manually, in terms of good quality and simplicity.

Comment: so you are already able to detect the rectangle points of stop sign which is drawn in your  input image.  What about going with these points by giving some offset ? Can you also share the source image alone so we can also try it ?

Comment: are you talking about pictures of stop signs? how general do you need this to be?

Comment: Are you trying to do an arbitrary perspective or to rectify to a face on view?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Actually I am more interested in conversion from automobile front camera images to Bird-eye-view

Comment: your question should have said so. -- it's a fixed transformation because the car will always be on the ground and the ground will always be flat. -- if either of those assumptions aren't met, you'll get funny distortions that you have to compensate by knowing how the ground is positioned _currently_, relative to the camera. -- a fixed homography can be calculated from model parameters such as the height of the camera above ground, its roll,pitch,yaw, its focal length/zoom, ... or just take a picture of something square lying on the ground, pick the points, `getPerspectiveTransform` and done

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks. For the second method, I kinda wrote a script. For the first method (using homography) is there a tutorial, or example I can look at? I am currently reading https://towardsdatascience.com/a-hands-on-application-of-homography-ipm-18d9e47c152f and trying to understand